# Why bitwise shift with 0 in JavaScript yields weird results in some cases

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

Just played around with unusual bitwise operations in JavaScript and I got some weird results in some cases:

***Usual cases***

```
1 << 0            // returns 1, makes sense
100 << 0          // returns 100, makes sense
100 >> 0          // returns 100, definitely makes sense
```

***But these, when shift by 0 bits, all yield zero***

```
9E99 << 0         // returns 0 ..... Why all bits are cleared?
9E99 >> 0         // returns 0 also  ..... All bits cleared?
Infinity >> 0     // returns 0
Infinity << 0     // returns 0
-Infinity << 0    // returns 0 .... Can't explain why
-0 << 0           // also yields 0 not -0 itself
-0 >> 0           // also resolved to 0
```

***What if Infinity and bitwise shift***

```
1 << Infinity     // returns 1  .. no changes
1024 << Infinity  // returns 1024 .. no changes
1024 >> Infinity  // returns 1024 .. no changes either
Infinity >> Infinity      // 0
Infinity << Infinity      // 0
```

Those cases above don't make much sense to me. *When shift an integer by zero bits, the value doesn't change*. ***But when you shift `Infinity` by 0 bits, it actually returns you 0***. Why?

I thought shifting any numeric value by 0 bit should not change its value, doesn't it?

Further, *when shift a small integer value by infinity bits, the value doesn't change at all*. But when you shift Infinity by any values, it is replaced by 0 instead.

I'm really curious why these phenomena happen? Is there any specifications or theory that explain these odd behaviors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the MDN:

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format.

All numbers in JavaScript are [IEEE754 double precision floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985). They're converted to 32 bits integers before being applied bitwise operators.

More precisely, this process is described in [**ToInt32** in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5):

[image]

As you see, the transformation of Infinities and `-0` is precisely described.

This is a binary truncation, which also explains why `9E99` is changed into `0`: This is most obvious if you look at the 32 bits at the right of `(9E99).toString(2)` (paste it in your console, they're all `0`).

Comment: *(Mathematical power notation, not XOR operator)* I have just tried `2^32 << 0` and get 0. Also tried `2^32 -1 << 0` and get -1. Your explanation is precise.

Answer (score 3):

Bit shifts and Logical operations in JavaScript are evaluated as 32-bit integers. Presence of << operator requires conversion of any object to int or 0 if the conversion fails. Infinity or 99e9 are valid ieee doubles, but fail to convert to int: 9e99 mod 2^32 == 0. A counter example 9e9|0 ==   410065408 illustrates the usage of modular algebra.

This works both ways: inf << inf is equivalent to 0 << 0.

Comment: I have tried several bitwise operations with 2^32 and found that when doing any bitwise operations, the numbers are binary truncated to 32 bits as you explained. 2^32 becomes 0, 2^32+1 becomes 1. I may look into other languages and see the differences in terms of specs.

Answer (score 0):

It is according to [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

Basically, JS compiler converts floating point arguments to 32 bit integer using the algorithm described in item 9.5 of ECMA-262. In most of the cases you mentioned the result of the conversion is 0.