# Why a positive number operated with bitwise or 0 not always positive in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

Why a positive number operated with bitwise or 0 not always positive in Javascript

For example:

```
3391700000|0
-903267296

4260919000|0
-34048296

2884900000|0
-1410067296
```

I'm using chrome 64-bit on Linux

related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12837315/1620210

Comment: just a quick guess: integer overflow?

Comment: now i should change all my codebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because JavaScript uses 32bit integers at most, but keep in mind every number is kind of a float in this language

If you want to truncate them to an unsigned 32bit value:

```
(3391700000|0) >>> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

**In JavaScript, the operands of bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in 2's complement format**. Thats why you got some loss of data and the truncated values are sometimes negative because of signed two's complement representation.

You can refer to [Why bitwise shift with 0 in JavaScript yields weird results in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673053/why-bitwise-shift-with-0-in-javascript-yields-weird-results-in-some-cases) thread which was asked by myself some time ago and some answers pointed out the possible issue with bitwise operators where your operands exceed 32-bit integers very comprehensively.